# String to space separated integer

Tags: c, string, integer

I have a string with integers in it (*in descending order*) then output should be space separated integers. Integers are not negative.

**INPUT:** `9876543` **OUTPUT:** `9 8 7 6 5 4 3`

**INPUT:** `109876543` **OUTPUT:** `10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3`

**INPUT:** `400399398397` **OUTPUT:** `400 399 398 397`

So I tried using `sscanf()` but was not able to get the desired result, this is the code I tried:

```
fgets(s1,100,stdin);  // Get string
while(sscanf(data1,"%d%n",&m1,&len)==1){
    b[i] = m1;    // Store the integers in the array
    data1 += len;
    i += 1;
}
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: How does the code know that `9876543` is to be separated into `98 76 54 3` or `987 654 3` or `9 8 7 6 5 4 3` or any other combination?

Comment: Yes, indeed that's the problem I am facing with the snippet

Comment: I am asking this from the requirements viewpoint. Given any string of numbers, e.g. as above. How do you, the user, want it broken up? Is there a consistent algorithm for all strings.

Comment: I wanted to try with `sscanf()` for this but as said there were many other possibilities. The only condition is the numbers will be in descending order.

Comment: Will the next number always be one less than the previous?

Comment: Yes the next number will be one less than the previous

Comment: You'll need to read the digits as a string and then parse and reparse the string.  Do you have to worry about 1000999998997 as a possible input?  (That's a nuisance because the first number has 4 digits but the rest have 3; your examples are all uniformly the same number of digits in each number.)

Comment: You can use a trial and error approach. Try the first digit. If the second digit is one less than try the third and so on. If not then take the first two digits and see if the number one less than that is in the next digits. If not then take the first three digits, upto 1/2 the length of the number. If nothing matches you have a malformed string.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The second example he gave has the first digit as `10` and other as `9 8 7 6 5 etc` So that condition needs to be taken care of.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje: oh — yes.  OK.  As you said, and as I said, the solution will need to parse and (if necessary) reparse the string until a solution is found or no solution is possible.  Further, there isn't a truly convenient function for doing this.  `sscanf()` can be told to scan 1 or 2 or 3 digits each time, but you have to create those formats on the fly, most probably.  Functions like `strtol()` or `atoi()` won't stop after N digits; they'll read as many as possible.  Ick!   (`109108107` … fun!)

Comment: Something like this? 1. Set no. of digits in a number to 1.
2. Take right-most digit from string and store it.
3. Take next right-most digit and see if it is 1 larger than stored value.
3a. If yes, then continue taking next digit.
3b. If no, increase the no. of digits in a number, and re-scan string from the right-most digit.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje How about posting your solution as an answer?

Comment: there's not only one unique answer. `9876543` can also be splitted as `98 76 54 3`, `987 65 43`, `98765 43`... `109876543` can be `109 87 65 43`, `109 87 6 5 4 3`... Which one do you want?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc _the next number will be one less than the previous_ (from [commnet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43992628/string-to-space-separated-integer#comment75014447_43992628))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comments and the additional answer, to parse and separate the string into a space separated series of integers decreasing by one, there are probably a number of differing approaches you can take. The biggest design question is whether you start with the length of the input string, cut it in half and then work backwards decreasing the number of digits you check for adjacent values by one -- or whether you start at the beginning and work toward the end incrementing the number of digits being considered along the way.

Regardless of the direction you choose, the twist is handling/checking adjacent values with a different number of digits. Your second example, `109876543`, hits at the heart of this twist, where you must code a way to check the *2-digit* value `10` against the next *single-digit* value in the series `9`. There is just no pretty way to do this. One reasonable way is to simply compute the smallest number that can be represented by `n`-digits (e.g. `10, 100, 1000, ...`). Essentially `10^(n-1)` (where we let `int expn = n - 1;`). If your first value `v1` is equal to `10^(n-1)`, then reduce the number of characters you consider for the next smallest values. Something like the following:

```
        while (expn--)                  /* loop to build 10 ^ (n-1)    */
            x10 *= 10;                  /* compute 10 ^ (n-1), 10, 100 */
        if (v1 == x10)                  /* compare against v1          */
            n--;                        /* reduce t2 by 1-char/digit   */
```

The remainder of the task is just basically a brute force check with a minimum number of validations necessary to protect array bounds, while handling adding values to your integer array (or however you want to store values until you validate or invalidate the remaining characters in the string) while you work your way through the remaining characters.

Putting all the pieces together, and noting there are many, many ways to code this, this example being only one, you could do something similar to the following. Note, the code simply handles the conversion from ASCII to `int` in the single-digit series case by subtracting `'0'` from the character value, for multi-digit conversions, `strtol` is used with a validation check of `errno`. The code works from beginning to end of the string incrementing the number of digits checked until the end of the string is reached. If a solution is found, a space-separated list of integers is output, otherwise, `"no solution found."` is output. The code is commented to help you work though it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXI 256

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int a[MAXI] = {0}, i = 1, idx = 0, n = 1, len;
    char *p = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "9876543";

    printf ("string   : %s\n", p);          /* original input string */

    len = (int)strlen (p);                  /* get length */

    while (i + n <= len && n < len) {       /* loop until conditions met */
        if (n >= MAXI) {                    /* protect int array bounds  */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: array full, %d elements filled.\n", n);
            break;
        }
        if (n == 1) {                       /* handle single digits series */
            if (p[i - 1] == p[i] + 1) {     /* previous equal current + 1? */
                if (!idx)                   /* if array index == 0 */
                    a[idx++] = p[i - 1] - '0';  /* store first integer */
                a[idx++] = p[i] - '0';      /* store current integer   */
                i++;                        /* increment string index  */
            }
            else
                n++, i = n, idx = 0;        /* increment n-digits to check */
        }                                   /* set i = n, zero array index */
        else {                              /* handle multi-digit values   */
            char t1[MAXI] = "", t2[MAXI] = "";  /* tmp strings for values  */
            int v1 = 0, v2 = 0,             /* tmp for coverted values     */
                expn = n - 1, x10 = 1,      /* 10 ^ expn for n-- test      */
                norig = n;                  /* n to restore on no match    */

            strncpy (t1, p + i - n, n);     /* copy n-digits for 1st value */

            errno = 0;
            v1 = (int) strtol (t1, NULL, 10);   /* convert to int/validate */
            if (errno) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: failed conversion, i: %d, n: %d\n",
                        i, n);
                return 1;
            }

            while (expn--)                  /* loop to build 10 ^ (n-1)    */
                x10 *= 10;                  /* compute 10 ^ (n-1), 10, 100 */
            if (v1 == x10)                  /* compare against v1          */
                n--;                        /* reduce t2 by 1-char/digit   */

            strncpy (t2, p + i, n);         /* copy n-digits for 2nd value */

            errno = 0;
            v2 = (int) strtol (t2, NULL, 10);   /* convert to int/validate */
            if (errno) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: failed conversion, i: %d, n: %d\n",
                        i, n);
                return 1;
            }

            if (v1 == v2 + 1) {             /* check decreasing values  */
                if (!idx)                   /* if array index == 0      */
                    a[idx++] = v1;          /* store first integer      */
                a[idx++] = v2;              /* store current integer    */
                i += n;                     /* increment string index   */
            }
            else {
                n += n < norig ? 2 : 1;     /* reset n if no match      */
                i = n;                      /* set string index to n    */
                idx = 0;                    /* reset array index to 0   */
            }
        } 
    }

    if (idx && n < len) {               /* if array has values, output  */
        printf ("integers :");
        for (int j = 0; j < idx; j++)
            printf (" %*d", n, a[j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
    else
        printf ("no solution found.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**note:** not all corner-cases have been evaluated and the input is presumed to contain only digits. (you are free to add the check for `isdigit` if you expect otherwise), further testing on your part should be done to satisfy yourself any odd-ball cases are sufficiently covered.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/intsepdecr
string   : 9876543
integers : 9 8 7 6 5 4 3

$ ./bin/intsepdecr 109876543
string   : 109876543
integers : 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3

$ ./bin/intsepdecr 400399398397
string   : 400399398397
integers : 400 399 398 397

$ ./bin/intsepdecr 400399398396
string   : 400399398396
no solution found.

$ ./bin/intsepdecr 101176543
string   : 101176543
no solution found.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

I can give a basic algorithm of how to go about this problem.

1. Convert the first `x` digits of the string into an integer (Initially `x=1`). You can even use a simple function like `strtoi` for this. (Let us say this number is N)
2. Find no of digits in `N-1`. Convert that many digits next into an integer.
3. Is the Converted value equal to `N-1`. If So, Continue and convert the rest of the string by repeating steps 2 & 3. (Need to Set `N = N-1`)
4. If not equal to `N-1`, Repeat from step 1, Only this time increment the number of digits converted.
5. Exit the program and declare a malformed string if you are not able to convert the entire string and `x` is greater than half the length of string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something i just whipped up i tested it against your cases and it works

Mind it is in c++ but it would be simple to convert to c.

```
string spaceNum(string in)
{
    string numConvBuff;

    size_t matchSize = 0;

    if (in.size() == 1)
    {
        return to_string(in[0] - '0');
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < in.size() / 2; i++)
    {
        numConvBuff = in.substr(0, i + 1);

        unsigned int numRes = stoul(numConvBuff) - 1;
        string numResStr = to_string(numRes);

        string n = in.substr(i + 1, numResStr.length());

        if(numRes == stoul(n))
            matchSize = i+1;
    }

    if (matchSize)
    {
        string out = in.substr(0, matchSize);
        unsigned int numRes = stoul(out);

        for (size_t i = matchSize; i < in.length();)
        {
            numRes--;
            string numResStr = to_string(numRes);
            string n = in.substr(i, numResStr.length());

            out += " " + n;
            i += numResStr.length();
        }

        return out;
    }

    return "";
}
```